# SwiftUI - FocusState opens keyboard on view state change

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view with Textfields and I am using FocusStates.

My problem is that when I want to show an error message, the Keyboard is showing up.
How can I hide the keyboard when the view is reloading?

```
struct SignInUI: View {
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case username, password
    }
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    @StateObject var viewModel: SignInViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .loading:
                ZStack {
                    content
                    ProgressView()
                }
                
            case .error:
                ZStack {
                    content
                    ErrorView()
                }
                
            case .loaded:
                content
            }
        }
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        VStack {
            PasswordTextField(field: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
            EmailTextField(field: $email)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
            
            ButtonView(text: "Sign In", action: {
                focusedField = nil
                viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `focusedField` to `nil` when the `ErrorView` appears:

```
case .error:
    ZStack {
        content
        ErrorView()
            .onAppear {
                focusedField = nil
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but still the Keyboard appears… Have no idea why.

Comment: What is changing, the `viewModel.state`?  Try putting the `.onAppear` on `Group { }.onAppear ...` instead and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be the most versatile way to disable keyboard.
You can add a state to detect isReloading state, and call this function to disable keyboard.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HideKeyboard: View {
    
    @State var username = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("User name (email address)", text: $username)
        Button("Hide Keyboard") {
            endEditing()
        }
    }
    private func endEditing() {
        // Call this function on any action you want to call from.
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but the keyboard still appears after the view is re rendered … no idea why